# How do I create this especific Add menu in Blender?

Tags: python, blender

im new in software developing in Blender. Im currently working on making a new mesh but im stuck trying to code a menu like the one in the image. [Add menu that appears when creating a mesh like a cube/cone/sphere...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZcWY.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.